# Set text in TextView in custom dialog

Tags: android, android-view, textview, android-alertdialog

I want to set the text in a TextView contained in a custom dialog programmatically, so that I can use `Html.fromHtml`. In what function should I call `setText`? I've tried doing it in `onCreateDialog`, but this does not actually change the text.

```
public class InfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.infodialog, null));

        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.info);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Text has been correctly set</h1>"));
        ...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
View content =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.infodialog, null);   
builder.setView(content);
TextView textView = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.info);
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the issue is that `Activity.findViewById()` only looks in the layout passed to the activity's `setContentView()` method, which in my case did not include the View used by the dialog.

Comment: Kind of late but you could also use `TextView tv = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.myDialogsTextView)`

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson kind of late too but i feel like your answer is more intuitive to me and i am using that for a similar issue of mine. thanks!